# SED change value between tags

Tags: sed

I have log file on unix like this:

```
#######################################
################start host1############
#######################################
##java serv
host1,def,java,es,dev L2,1,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M1,1,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev N1,1,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M5,1,dev w,fr


##c++ serv
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev L2,1,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M1,1,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M4,1,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M5,1,dev w,fr
#######################################
################end host1##############
#######################################

#######################################
################start host2############
#######################################
##java serv
host2,def,java,es,dev L2,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev M1,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,java,es,dev M5,0,dev w,fr


##c++ serv
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev L2,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev M1,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host2,def,ESServer,es,dev M5,0,dev w,fr
#######################################
################end host2##############
#######################################
```

I need change value from 1 to 0, in all strings between tags "host1". For example:

```
#######################################
################start host1############
#######################################
##java serv
host1,def,java,es,dev L2,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,java,es,dev M5,0,dev w,fr


##c++ serv
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev L2,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev L3,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M4,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev N1,0,dev w,fr
host1,def,ESServer,es,dev M5,0,dev w,fr
#######################################
################end host1##############
#######################################
```

So,is it possible to write regular expression on SED? I'll try to write but can't understand how to continue... This expression change all value from 1 to 0

```
sed 's/,0,/,1,/g' file
```

UPDATED.

Thanks all! Now it changed, but if I want change value in tag java or c++ in host1 for example?
Something like this:
`sed '/start host1//c++/,/end host1/s/,0,/,1,/g' file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
sed '/start host1/,/end host1/s/,0,/,1,/g'
```

`/start host1/` is a starting address `/end host1/` is a ending address.

See [Sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed '/^host1/s/,0,/,1,/g'
```

only replace line starting with host1 (`/^host1/`), rest your noted replacement was fine